# .NET Proxy simple WCF service not working

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy

I've created an aspx page that serves as a proxy to a WCF service hosted somewhere else on the intranet. The goal is to have a page that is not bound by cross site scripting restrictions and can work with any WCF web service.

I've got the call working and my debugger picks up the request but the data isn't being sent along and is null.  I do have this working when not using a proxy (jquery ajax) when within same domain. Fiddler2 isn't picking up my HttpWebRequest for whatever reason so I can't see what's actually getting sent along.

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong the way I'm posting the data? Any way to get fiddler to pick up the WebHttpRequest?

**Proxy.aspx**

```
// var data = Request.Form["d"];
// ProxyRequest r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProxyRequest>(data);
var r = new { ServiceName = "AccountService.svc", Type = "POST", MethodName = "AjaxFindCompany", 
    Data = "{\"AccountNumber\":null,\"Address\":{\"City\":\"Pittsburgh\",\"Country\":null,\"State\":\"PA\",\"Street1\":\"1 Ave\",\"ZipCode\":\"15222\"},\"BusinessName\":\"AUto\"}" };

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}?{3}", "http://localhost:2749", r.ServiceName, r.MethodName, r.Data));
request.Method = r.Type;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

StreamReader contentReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
Response.ContentType = response.ContentType;
Response.Write(contentReader.ReadToEnd());
```

**IAccountService.cs**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "*", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
MatchCompanyResponse AjaxFindCompany(MatchCompanyRequest request);
```

**AccountService.cs**

```
public MatchCompanyResponse FindCompany(MatchCompanyRequest request)
{
    AccountHandler handler = new AccountHandler();
    return handler.FindCompany(request);
}

public MatchCompanyResponse AjaxFindCompany(MatchCompanyRequest request)
{
    // after calling proxy.aspx the debugger captures here but
    // request is null...
    return FindCompany(request);
}
```

Comment: If your service address is localhost, you could try this link to fix your Fiddler problem: http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic

Comment: Also, if you aren't already, make sure you ensure your web page and web service are both configured to return stack traces/full exception details - it might shed some light on the specific problem.

Comment: Finally for detailed debugging on the WCF side, you should enable WCF diagnostics - something is clearly going wrong in the WCf pipelione before your code is hit. This will tell you what that is.

Comment: Thank you much for the tips. The fiddler localhost fix worked like a charm and I didn't have to enable the others. The problem ultimately was the wrong content type being sent to my WCF method. And coincidentally I'm doing some of this from within saleslogix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a POST request, the data goes in the body of the request, not in the URI. So the request should be something similar to this:

```
var r = new { ServiceName = "AccountService.svc", Type = "POST", MethodName = "AjaxFindCompany",  
    Data = "{\"AccountNumber\":null,\"Address\":{\"City\":\"Pittsburgh\",\"Country\":null,\"State\":\"PA\",\"Street1\":\"1001 Liberty Ave\",\"ZipCode\":\"15222\"},\"BusinessName\":\"AUto\"}" }; 

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", "http://localhost:2749", r.ServiceName, r.MethodName)); 
request.Method = r.Type;
Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
byte[] reqBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(r.Data as string);
reqStream.Write(reqBytes, 0, reqBytes.Length);
reqStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
StreamReader contentReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()); 
Response.ContentType = response.ContentType; 
Response.Write(contentReader.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: With this I get a 400 error and the debugger never picks it up. And my fiddler still isn't picking anything up..

Comment: The 400 problem was due to content type